# Running unit test with the Yii framework

Tags: php, yii, phpunit

**Background**

I'm using the Yii framework and have just started creating some unit tests for my project. I am trying to run my test via command line.

```
$cd www/site/webapp/protected/tests
$phpunit --verbose --colors unit/TaxRateTest.php
```

**Problem**

I keep getting a strange response that i'm not sure about and I don't know how to fix. It doesn't seem to run my test instead invokes the Yii command runner.

```
Yii command runner (based on Yii v1.1.14-dev)
Usage: /usr/local/bin/phpunit <command-name> [parameters...]

The following commands are available:
    - message
    - migrate
    - shell
    - webapp

To see individual command help, use the following:
    /usr/local/bin/phpunit help <command-name>
```

**Unit Test class**

```
class TaxRateTest extends CDbTestCase {
    public $fixtures = array(
        'organisation'    => 'Organisation',
    );

    public function testPopulateTaxRateTable() {
        $organisation = New Organisation();
        $organisation->display_name = "Test Organisation";
        $organisation->country_id = 1;
        $organisation->plan_id = Yii::app()->params['default_plan_id'];

        $organisation->save();

        $tax_rates = TaxRate::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('organisation_id'=>$organisation->id));

        $this->assertEquals(count(TaxAccounts::$accounts), count($tax_rates));

        //setup the default tax accounts
        //TaxAccounts::initialize($this->id);
    }

}
```

**Question**

What am I doing wrong? 
How should I be running my tests?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with tests/bootstrap.php. I had updated the path for the $yiit variable and pointed it at point to /packages/yiisoft/yii/framework/yiic.php not /packages/yiisoft/yii/framework/yiit.php.

My bootstrap.php file now looks like this:

```
<?php

// change the following paths if necessary
$yiit=dirname(__FILE__).'/../packages/yiisoft/yii/framework/yiit.php';
$config=dirname(__FILE__).'/../config/test.php';

require_once($yiit);
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/WebTestCase.php');

Yii::createWebApplication($config);
```